# Tool to analyze and compare logic of similar functions?

Tags: c#, static-analysis

I recently picked up a project with a large code base containing much duplication.  The problem is that the duplicated functionality was not written by the same people nor copied between them.

So, are there tools that I can use to compare the actual logic of two functions?  Here are some of the constraints that would be useful.

- Ignore order where order is unimportant (such as setting properties)
- Variable names should be analyzed for similarity, but not required to match if used for the same reasons
- Look deep into the other methods called by the functions being compared and flatten the logic for comparison

Ideally, the tool would produce a single function output.  The actual logical differences would be highlighted in some fashion.  It may even be in a form that defines separate functions for the differences in the logic, passing them into the main function which contains the logic that is identical.

This does sound like a tall order, but has anyone come across tools which attempt to do any of these things?

**Edit**

While there are some cool tools mentioned, it doesn't look like any of them will take the content of called functions into account when comparing the logic of two methods.  If I'm incorrect, please let me know!

Comment: I think such "tool" exists and it's a human programmer :)

Comment: @vulkanino: Does that mean you'll come analyze the code for me?  I'll only need to spend $50-$200 once and be able to use this "tool" any time I need it?

Comment: :) I cost more, but surely you'll find a cheaper "tool" on VWorker for example ;)

Comment: There are a ton of tools out there if you Google. I saw *Simian* pop up high on the results list. Try some of them out and see if they meet your needs. I doubt any of them go to the extent that you'd like, though.

Comment: @DBM: That's exactly my problem.  All the tools seem to stop at the level of the function they started at.  What I really need is something that will dive deep into the child functions as well.

Comment: You want a tool that can prove the equivalence of two functions.  In general, you can't do this; Turing is in the way.  One might be able to implement this for special cases.  But whatever the tool is that does this, it has to be able to the languages, resolve names, construct an accurate call tree, and then match functions (and thier subsidiary trees) in the face of different algorithms and and data representations.  As a practical matter, you'll find IMHO that these functions are NOT exactly the same; you now have to define "similar" functionality.   Good luck with this; its a holy grail.

Comment: @IraBaxter: If you were surfing a large pile of code looking for "similarities" this might be a problem.  However, pointing to two specific functions and delineating between code that does the same thing and code that does not would be much easier.

Comment: @JohnFisher: You miss the point.  There's a Turing halting theorem in the way in general.   I agree that for many small functions doing "simple" things that "you" (a human or tool) might have a chance, but I'd guess that if you have any complexity (including functions that call others) "you" will have a hard time.   PS: I thought your problem was a code base with much "duplication"; doesn't that mean you have to "surf a large pile of code" looking for such? Surely that's how you noticed.

Comment: @IraBaxter: I think you miss the point.  (It's my question after all.)  This large pile has many already discovered functions with similarities.  A tool that can divide between similar and non-similar is all that is required when pointed at two functions.  Nowhere near a halting problem.  Just mark it as questionable if it can't tell.

Comment: @JohnFisher:  We've agreed you aren't looking for identical code.  So if two pieces of code aren't exactly the same, when do you mark them as "might be similar"?  Everything in your code base has this property. That's awful lot of "might be similar".

Comment: @IraBaxter:  We could design the thing right here, but my question was about whether one already existed - so I'd rather not.

Answer (score 6):

If you download the developer preview of Visual Studio vNext Ultimate, it includes a new Code Clone Detection feature:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205279(v=vs.110).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2011/12/13/visual-studio-11-developer-preview-code-clone-detection-aka-code-clone-analysis.aspx

The download link for the developer preview Visual Studio:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27543

Comment: This looks pretty close.  Hopefully, I can get a chance to try it.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this has the same difficulty that the rest of the tools have -- it doesn't examine the code in the called functions.  (So if function A calls B, C, and D then the code in B, C, and D are irrelevent to the comparison of functions A and Z.)

Comment: I have no idea why this answer was upvoted let alone marked with the bounty.   The Visual studio clone detector matches sequences of tokens.  It can't reliably find function boundaries, let alone parse the code, figure out names and types, or determine if functions are similar.   It WILL find code that IS copy and pasted; OP explicitly said the code he wanted to match was NOT copied and pasted.

Answer (score 5):

If you have ReSharper there is a ReSharper plug-in [Agent Ralf](http://code.google.com/p/agentralphplugin).

Quote of Agent Ralf's homepage:

> In some cases two given methods can be functionally equivalent (same inputs produce the same outputs and side effects) but not textually equivalent. For example, two methods might differ only in the naming of local variables, and are otherwise identical. Agent Ralph can detect this situation, and others like it, and determine that the methods are **functionally equivalent**.

Answer (score 1):

There is Duplicate Detection and Consolidation feature on CodeRush. (http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/duplicate_code.xml)

This feature detected duplicate code. i am not sure that it is able to detect/compare logic of similar functions.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

**You could always code your own.** This falls under proper unit testing.

IF your similar functions modify some state instance/class, THEN use reflection to test if the property values of the resulting classes are equal.

IF your similar functions modify a database, THEN make a copy of the database run each function on a copy and compare.

But this probably all starts with proper unit tests. If you know all your possible "use cases" then when you find that the output of two (or more) functions is the same for all of these "use cases" you can safely keep one function and throw away the repeats as unnecessary.

**Another option is to get actual requirements for what the code/functions are doing.** Learning what your system is actually trying to accomplish make refactoring old or repetitious code much easier.

---

The tools that check for logic duplication will only take you as far as you're willing to work. If you say the current tools don't take into account nested functions or functions that call other functions, then why not refactor the code to inline those called functions so your tool will work? You're just looking for a panacea if you don't even want to refactor method A (which calls methods B, C, D) into method AA which in-lines the code from B, C, D.

**IN SHORT** with some "work" you can get the current tools to work for you. You may want to contribute to the open source tools to compensate for the failing you mention.

Comment: The thrust of your answer assumes that the functions are **identical**.  However, I know that the functions are different and am looking for the similarities.

Comment: Of course, I could refactor the code to make it easy for the tools to do what they can.  But by that time I've already done most of the work -- isn't that the point of getting a tool to do it?

Comment: "With some work"?  Have you actually done this?  I flat out think you are wrong.

Comment: @Ira Baxter - Have I 'refactored old/legacy functions that are thousands of lines of BOOLshit outsourced code that all seemed to do similar tasks but in entirely roundabout ways'? Yes, yes I have, and while it's a little time consuming it's not at all difficult. Being a programmer means being able to jump in at any point in the development life cycle. So, to keep the subjective unfounded opinions going (only in jest of course) I flat out think you are lazy.

Comment: @LastCoder: Yes, I can believe you've done this by hand; that makes you just like most of the rest of us that program for a living.  That is irrelevant. The discussion is whether you can build tools to do this.  Before you decide that I'm lazy, or don't have serious experience building tools in this area, you might check my bio.

Comment: @Ira Baxter - Nope, the discussion was (the full quote) ""IN SHORT with some "work" you can get the current tools to work for you."" John Fisher explained the current tools didn't follow sub functions, so I replied "with some work" you could inline those sub methods and allow the current tools to work AND/OR you can contribute to the open source tools to try and help fix that specific issue. Have I refactored code to allow for automated testing/code gen/refactoring to work correctly, yes yes I have. Can't quote one thing then jump to an entirely different point to defend it, that's just silly.

Comment: @LastCoder: What "current tools" work for his task? Name one.  My claim is that detecting "equivalent (not identical) functions" is really hard already [There have been some research tools built to normalize code fragments, but in general I know of NO available tools that do this], and that detecting "similar functions" is harder.  You're making some kind of claim that implies this is possible and practical.   I'm just not buying this argument.

Comment: @Ira Baxter - Ok... from the answers to this very question ReSharper (Agent Ralph plugin) uses the C# syntax tree to find functionally equivalent methods. The latest Visual Studio preview has built in code clone detection. More specifically I'd probably modify the ReSharper plugin to check outputs and side-effects for within reason (some percentage) similarity, rather than complete equality. But there's a great deal of difference between FUNCTIONALLY EQUAL (current tools exist) and SIMILAR (current tools would need to be modified). ""You're just looking for a panacea if you don't even...""

Comment: @LastCoder: Agent Ralf is a *code clone detector*.  It finds things that are essentially copies of code.   OP specifically said "not written or copied by people".  So I reject this as an example. Similarly I reject other clone detectors.   He wants to detect things that are functionally similar but not copied.  Did you read his question?

Comment: @Ira Baxter - The code clone detectors referenced don't need exact copies, they ignore variable names, instruction ordering, and look purely at output and side-effects. In my last reply I alluded to how I would turn that code clone (equality) detector into a code similarity detector using partial/weighted matching of the output and side-effects (Did you read it?). No panacea exists (no magic tool to rewrite all old code into concise new code), old code needs to be refactored, tools need to be improved, if you take some time you can get an approximate solution. I'm done with this asinine thread